# Help identifying SMD components

Tags: transistors, diodes, integrated-circuit, identification

I am having trouble identifying some components in this circuit. I am not sure if these are commercially available or not, so that's why I am asking.

The components are shown below:

1. I believe this would be a transistor.

[image]

2. I believe this would be a diode.

[image]

3. Unsure.

[image]

4. It has a marking like a diode, but really unsure if it is.

[image]

5. I believe this would also be a diode.

[image]

Edit:

6. Unsure about this component as well

[image]

Edit2:
Thanks to @Phil G who found both 4th and 6th to be dual transistors. And the meantime i found CY806(1st) to be 2SC881-Y and 5th to be BAS21-O3W.
But if anyone could help me with the 2nd and 3rd, it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The [SMD Codebook](http://www.marsport.org.uk/smd/mainframe.htm) is a useful resource for identifying these, of the parts you show, I find [UMH11TN](https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-1387912825521495953) for the third one, and [BAS21-03W](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BAS21SERIES-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=5546d4624933b8750149880ded0b7e1a) for the fifth one, but the marking in the datasheet for the last one doesn't accord with the marking in the database.

Comment: how did you find the 3. to be UMH11TN through the marking on the case? In the linked datasheet the case doesn't look like the same case as in figure 3.
Also how did you find the last one(5.)?

Comment: Sorry, that was 4. For the last one, Z1 leads you to http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/bipolar/umz1ntr-e.pdf